# How to only make one legend name italic in base R plot?

Tags: r, string, plot, legend, font-style

I want to add a legend to a plot in which **only one of the legend names is italicized**. I'm using `plot()` in base R.

- However, I need that italicized line to contain variable numbers, so I use `bquote`.

What I've tried does not work:

```
  a <- 2 ; b <- 5
  plot(a,b)
  l1 <- bquote(Italic ~ .(a) + .(b))
  l2 <- bquote(a + b)
  legend(x='topright',legend = bquote(italic(.(l1))))
  legend(x='topleft',legend = c(bquote(italic(.(l1))),l2))
```

- Notice that when I leave the expression on its own (RIGHT LEGEND), it italicizes correctly. However, when I add the text for other legend lines, it messes up (LEFT LEGEND).

[image]

How do I properly do this?

<sup>Note: I'd rather have a solution that *doesn't* require multiple calls to `legend()`.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `text.font = 3`, say:

```
legend(x='topleft',legend = c(bquote((.(l1))),l2), text.font=c(3,1))
```

Comment: then use text.font=c(3,1) to specify what line you want italicized. edited on my answer. Even text.font=c(3, NA) works well.

Comment: great! Your edited solution does the trick! Thanks! I will wait to see if others propose any ideas the rest of the evening but will accept your solution if no one does.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `as.expression` to coerce everything into an expression object.

```
a <- 2
b <- 5
plot(a,b)
legend("topleft", legend = c(as.expression(bquote(italic("Italic: "*.(a)*" + "*.(b)))),
    as.expression(bquote("Non Italic: "*.(a)*" + "*.(b)))) )
```

To modify your example

```
a <- 2
b <- 5
plot(a,b)
l1 <- bquote(Italic ~ .(a) + .(b))
l2 <- bquote(a + b)
legend("topleft", legend =  c(as.expression(bquote(italic(.(l1)))),
                            as.expression(bquote(.(l2))) ))
```

Comment: A little busier of a solution, but this works great! Thanks, @d.b. :)